# SequelizeJs ManyToMany Relation with ExpressJs Routes

Tags: javascript, express, sequelize.js, many-to-many, associations

I'm trying to learn `Sequelize.js` and I'm confused about its Many-To-Many Association.
What I've tried to do is simple Tasks Management with Users. Each task can be assignable to other users.

So, there's `Users`, `Tasks` and `TaskContributors` tables.

First, I made the POC version of my idea with `Express.js`. Then I found that I don't know how to insert to the Relational Table within different router.

Here are the model codes.

**User Model**

```js
'use strict'
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define(
    'User',
    {
      uid: { type: DataTypes.UUID, defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4 },
      name: DataTypes.STRING,
      password: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    {},
  )
  User.associate = function (models) {
    User.belongsToMany(models.Task, {
      as: 'Contributors',
      through: 'TaskContributors',
      foreignKey: 'userId',
    })
  }
  return User
}
```

**Task Model**

```js
'use strict'
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Task = sequelize.define(
    'Task',
    {
      uid: { type: DataTypes.UUID, defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4 },
      name: DataTypes.STRING,
      description: DataTypes.TEXT,
      status: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    },
    {},
  )
  Task.associate = function (models) {
    Task.belongsToMany(models.User, {
      as: 'Task',
      through: 'TaskContributors',
      foreignKey: 'taskId',
    })
  }
  return Task
}
```

**TaskContributor Model**

```js
'use strict'
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const TaskContributor = sequelize.define(
    'TaskContributor',
    {
      userId: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: { model: 'Users', key: 'id' },
      },
      taskId: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: { model: 'Tasks', key: 'id' },
      },
      userStatus: { allowNull: false, type: DataTypes.STRING },
    },
    {},
  )
  TaskContributor.associate = function (models) {}
  return TaskContributor
}
```

---

Routers

**Users Router**

```js
router.get('/create/:name', (req, res) => {
  User.create({ name: req.params.name, password: '123' })
    .then((result) => res.send(result))
    .catch((err) => res.status(500).send(err))
})
```

**Tasks Router**

```js
router.get('/create/:userId/:name', (req, res) => {
  const { userId, name } = req.params

  User.findOne({ where: { uid: userId } }).then(async (user) => {
    console.log(user)
    const maybeTask = await user
      .addTask({
        name,
        description: '',
        status: false,
        through: { userStatus: 'owner' },
      })
      .catch((err) => err)
    if (maybeTask instanceof Error) res.status(500).send(maybeTask)

    res.send(maybeTask)
  })
})
```

---

When I tried to create new Task, it said `user.addTask is not a function`.

From what I understand from the Docs is that they showed how to create M-M association with two `model.create()` Objects, but not with the scenario like creating in different file.

Comment: Did you register associations correctly in Sequelize before any queries?

Comment: @Anatoly I think I register them correctly according to my knowledge.